# New VM machine on Azure is not connecting to website and throw 403 error

Tags: azure, vps

I'm trying to enter growtopiagame.com on my new installed virtual machine on Azure, but whenever I enter with google chrome, it throwes 403 Forbidden error and won't connect to website.

I also tried to ping via CMD, and returns "Request timed out".

What could be the possible problem? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site you want to join is hosted on AWS, it is possible that the administrator has blocked the IP addresses of Azure.